# Public link Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I am trying to create a Dashboard in power bi that is public, but the publish to web (public) option does not appear, I tried to enable the option from the Admin Portal in the settings but it tells me that

"To enable Publish to Web, you need to disable Block Public Internet Access first"

When I try this, it tells me that I can't disable the lock because of this:

[Can't disabe block public internet access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGyPL.png)

I need to be able to have a public link that anyone can access without having to register or log in.

Thank you!!

I have the data in a MySQL database and additionally I have a power bi premium account

Comment: So you have Power BI configured to use a private endpoint? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-security-private-links